# Visual Studio 2012 : Qvec-report:2 link error

Tags: visual-studio, vectorization

I'm trying to use /Qvec-report:2 with Visual Studio 2012 during compile to see which loops of my code have been auto-vectorized or not. However, I keep getting this error message:

LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Qvec-report:2'; ignored

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Initially I'd installed VS 2010 and VS 2012 on the same machine. I think that must had something to do with. When I create a NEW PROJECT with VS 2012 and run /Qvec-report:2 as a compiler option, I am able to succesfully see the desired output. But when I add that to my existing project (Originally created in VS 2010), I get this weird any error. Any tips will be greatly appreciated ... I've spent 2 days to no avail. I thought it might have been due to conflicting .NET frameworks, but I've ruled that out as an issue ...

Comment: I have a Windows Form object as part of the project and I suspect that is an issue somehow ....

Comment: Isn't the option `Qvec-report` specific to Intel compilers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you added the option as a linker option by mistake.  Please it in the C/C++ compiler command line section.  And ensure your optimization level is set to /O2 (maximize speed)